# How to copy items from one list box to another list box?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, listboxitem

In my web application , I am having 2 List box as **"MenuBox" and "UpdatedBox"**. The MenuBox items were populated from Database using Dataset. Now If I select a Item in MenuBox and Click **"Move"** button, **the selected Item has to be copied to "UpdatedBox"**.... Can any one tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Try this one this is tested code.

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
            ListBox2.ClearSelection();
        }
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

ListBox `SelectionMode` can be set single or multiple, in both cases below code will work

```
int[] selection = MenuBox.GetSelectedIndices();
while (selection.Length >0)
{
    UpdatedBox.Items.Add(MenuBox.Items[selection[0]].ToString());
    MenuBox.Items.RemoveAt(selection[0]);
    selection = MenuBox.GetSelectedIndices();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 while(ListBox1.Items.Count!=0)
 {
    for(int i=0;i<ListBox1.Items.Count;i++)
    {
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: while you need while?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this.

```
UpdatedBox.Items.Add(MenuBox.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: This loop works, when all the items has to be copied to the UpdatedBox. I need a particular selected Item....

Comment: @Jalpesh please do answer very specific as context. That code is copied all elements of 1 list to 2 list box.